# Concurrency on javax.net.ssl.trustStore?

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail

I have a web application which uses 3rd party jars to provide payments with bank cards. Communication is made via SSL.

I also implemented functionality which will send confirmation e-mail (JavaMail) after the payment is made with code like this:

```
// property list
Properties properties = new Properties();

// host
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", smptServer);
// authorization
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
// STARTTLS
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
// port
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
// trust all certificates
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");
// debug
properties.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
```

The problem is: bank software sets such system parameters:

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
javax.net.ssl.keyStore
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType
javax.net.ssl.trustStore
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
```

to custom keystore which contains certificates.

As result I have a situation when bank software is working, but I can't send emails or  mail is working, but bank software is not:
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

In short, as I understand JavaMail must access Java cacerts (java/jre/lib/security/cacerts), but bank software must use custom keystore... but javax.net.ssl parameters can link to only one keystore.
If I import SMTP server certificate in bank keystore, then PKIX error is rised.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to put all the certs in a single trust store.  If that's not working, you may need help from a security expert.  See [SSLNOTES.txt](http://javamail.java.net/docs/SSLNOTES.txt) for tips for debugging these problems.

As a last resort, you can use [MailSSLSocketFactory](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/util/MailSSLSocketFactory.html) to set your own TrustManager, or set the mail..ssl.trust property to the server you want to trust.

Comment: mail.smtp.ssl.trust already contained * to trust all servers. But this did not work. The usage of MailSSLSocketFactory resolved the issue. Thank you! You are my saver!